# Compare subsequent row of a dataframe column (having string data) and if any of the string matches then record the timestamp and amount of duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Eg 1: As in above case string "CPU_001" matches in row 0 and 1, then we need to record User was high for 2 mins duration (as each row is of 1 min duration)  and Idle was high for 1 min duration

Eg 2: "CPU_005" is common in row 2 and 3, then CPU_005 was high for 2 mins duration and CPU_005 high for 7 mins (for next 6 rows) duration

Below is the dataframe details. Please let me know in case any further info is needed.

`above_thres` column contain name of column having values above 99.5 only.

```
from pandas import Timestamp

dataFrame = 

    {'Time-dur': {1: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:46:42'),
      7: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:47:42'),
      15: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:48:42'),
      23: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:49:42'),
      31: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:50:42'),
      39: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:51:42'),
      47: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:52:42'),
      55: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:53:42'),
      63: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:54:42'),
      71: Timestamp('2021-12-22 16:55:42')},
     'CPU_001': {1: 99.7,
      7: 99.6,
      15: 0.0,
      23: 0.0,
      31: 99.9,
      39: 0.0,
      47: 0.0,
      55: 0.0,
      63: 0.0,
      71: 0.0},
     'CPU_002': {1: 0.0,
      7: 0.0,
      15: 0.0,
      23: 0.0,
      31: 0.0,
      39: 0.0,
      47: 0.0,
      55: 0.0,
      63: 0.0,
      71: 0.0},
     'CPU_003': {1: 0.0,
      7: 0.0,
      15: 0.0,
      23: 0.0,
      31: 0.0,
      39: 0.0,
      47: 0.0,
      55: 0.0,
      63: 0.0,
      71: 0.0},
     'CPU_004': {1: 100.0,
      7: 70.0,
      15: 100.0,
      23: 100.0,
      31: 100.0,
      39: 100.0,
      47: 100.0,
      55: 100.0,
      63: 100.0,
      71: 100.0},
     'CPU_005': {1: 0.0,
      7: 100.0,
      15: 99.8,
      23: 0.0,
      31: 0.0,
      39: 0.0,
      47: 0.0,
      55: 0.0,
      63: 0.0,
      71: 0.0},
     'above_thres': {1: 'CPU_001, CPU_004',
      7: 'CPU_001, CPU_005',
      15: 'CPU_004, CPU_005',
      23: 'CPU_005',
      31: 'CPU_001, CPU_005',
      39: 'CPU_005',
      47: 'CPU_005',
      55: 'CPU_005',
      63: 'CPU_005',
      71: 'CPU_005'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataFrame )
df.head()
```

I'm looking for an output which indicate usage of which CPU is above value 99.5 and for how much duration. i.e in above case usage of CPU_001 is above threshold for 2 mins (2021-12-22 16:46:42 to 2021-12-22 16:47:42) and for 1 min at time : 2021-12-22 16:50:42 another case CPU_005 was above threshold for 9 mins (2021-12-22 16:47:42 to 2021-12-22 16:55:42) Output can be stored in any convenient and readable format.

Expected output can be like :

```
output_dict = {"CPU_001" : {
    "count" : 3,
    "interval" : [['2021-12-22 16:46:42', '2021-12-22 16:47:42'], ['2021-12-22 16:50:42','2021-12-22 16:50:42']],
    "duration" : [2, 1]},
"CPU_002" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "interval" : [],
    "duration" : []},
"CPU_003" : {
    "count" : 0,
    "interval" : [],
    "duration" : []},
"CPU_004" : {
    "count" : 2,
    "interval" : [['2021-12-22 16:46:42', '2021-12-22 16:46:42'], ['2021-12-22 16:48:42','2021-12-22 16:48:42']],
    "duration" : [1, 1]}
               
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm looking for an output which indicate usage of which CPU is above value 99.5 and for how much duration. 
i.e in above case usage of CPU_001 is above threshold for 2 mins (2021-12-22 16:46:42 to 2021-12-22 16:47:42) and for 1 min at time : 2021-12-22 16:50:42
another case CPU_005 was above threshold for 9 mins (2021-12-22 16:47:42 to 2021-12-22 16:55:42)        
Output can be stored in any convenient and readable format.

Comment: Please add that to your question. Preferably in the format of an expected output, e.g., an expected dataframe.

Comment: Also, please show any code you already have, and what part you are stuck. Unless you expect us to solve your problem completely and do the work for you.

Comment: Updated the problem statement, it's my first time posting of a question over satckoverflow hence few issue while posting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had a similar problem not too long ago and I believe you can reuse my code:

```
dataFrame2= dataFrame.set_index('Time-dur').drop(columns=['above_thres'])
binary = pd.DataFrame(0, index=dataFrame2.index, columns=dataFrame2.columns)
binary[dataFrame2> 99.5] = 1
durations = pd.DataFrame(0, index=binary.index, columns=binary.columns)
for column in binary.columns:
    sr = binary[column]
    cnt: pd.Series = sr.groupby(sr.ne(sr.shift()).cumsum()).value_counts().reset_index(level=0, drop=True) #  This is also from SO, but cannot remember where, sorry... 
    if len(cnt) == 0:
        continue
    cnt.name = 'count'
    cnt = cnt.reset_index()
    idx_dur = cnt['count'].cumsum().shift(1)
    idx_dur[0] = 0
    idx_dur += sr.index.get_loc(sr.first_valid_index())
    cnt.index = sr.iloc[idx_dur].index
    cnt = cnt.loc[cnt[column] == 1, 'count']
    durations.loc[cnt.index, column] = cnt
```

The df `durations` contains the number of subsequent rows with a value above 99.5%. Assuming that your rows are equally spaced, you can simply multiply this value with the corresponding `TimeDelta` (in this case 1 minute) if necessary.

Comment: Thanks C Hecht for your quick response. It serve my query in much better way than i expected !! Due to lack of reputation (as this is my first posting) I couldn't like your code, my apology for the same.

Comment: Happy to help! You can still mark the question as answered so that other people know that they do not need to worry about it anymore. Just click the tick-mark next to the answer.